# Conditionally Create a variable

Tags: ansible

I have some python code that runs in multiple environments.  The code checks for the existence of environment variables, and takes a slightly different path depending on what environment variable is defined.  The code is:

```
def _get_sink_to_function():
    # Determine which path we send data to, based on env variables
    # One of the following env variables must be present.
    funcdict = {
        'LOG_SINK':      _post_gzip_to_log_sink,
        'FIREHOSE_SINK': _post_gzip_to_firehose_sink
    }
    for v in funcdict.keys():
        if os.environ.get(v):
            return funcdict[v]
    return None

main():
    sink_to_func = _get_sink_to_function()
    if not sink_to_func:
        raise AssertionError('Missing mandatory env variable')
    ...
    sink_to_func(gzip_data)
```

The environment variables are set using ansible.

Therefore, I would like to conditionally create the environement variable.

For example, in this (valid) ansible code:

```
LOG_SYNC: "{% if logger == 'one' %}path-to-the-log{% endif %}"
```

LOG_SYNC is always defined, sometimes with a value of "path-to-the-log", and sometimes as empty.  I want LOG_SYNC not to be defined at all if logger is not equal to 'one'.

In other words, I want something like:

```
{% if logger == 'one' %}
  LOG_SYNC: "path-to-the-log"
{% endif %}
```

But, that does not seem to be allowed.

Comment: Seems like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)... Add some actual context to get decent advice.

Comment: I added the context.  Please let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: How do you set environment with ansible? Depending on that, you can, for example, use `ternary` filter to set environment object.

Answer (score -1):

The compiler, in whatever language you have written code, will need the variable to be defined first,  if it is going to be used anytime later.

so you will need to define the variable, assign value NULL then it will not occupy any memory

Comment: The yaml code I'm writing is defining an environment variable that will be used by python code.  The python code will check the if the environment variable exists.  If the env variable exists, the python code will try to use the variable.  If the env does not exist, the python code will take an alternative path.  So, I really don't want the environment variable to exist at all.  Existing with zero length is not as desirable.

Comment: Roger, thanks for adding details to clarify, Konstantin answer was based on question details at that time